# Making Python Logging work async with Celery

Tags: logging, celery

I have logging setup. In particular, I have SMTPHandler. I would like to have it happen async. I'd like to use celery to make that happen. Is that possible?

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("logger")

mail_handler = STMPHandler(...)
mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
...
logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
```

Comment: Have you considered logging solutions like [fluentd](http://fluentd.org/)? This sounds a bit like shooting a mosquito with a bazooka.